# ViewWrappedExcepetion error is null, then not null

Tags: http, angular

I'm starting with angular2. And I try to get data from an php script.

I followed the turorial at the angular docs. But I recently get this confusing error messeage:

```
zone.js:463 ViewWrappedException {_wrapperMessage: "Error in app/components/catch-data/catch-data.component.html:7:5", _originalException: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at DebugAppView._View_CatchDataComponent0.de…, _originalStack: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefine…t/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:9996:18)", _context: DebugContext, _wrapperStack: "Error: Error in app/components/catch-data/catch-da…tChangesInternal (AppComponent.template.js:121:8)"}
```

containing this message:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at DebugAppView._View_CatchDataComponent0.detectChangesInternal (CatchDataComponent.template.js:62)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:9996)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:10084)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (core.umd.js:10016)
    at DebugAppView._View_CatchDataComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (CatchDataComponent_Host.template.js:36)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:9996)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:10084)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (core.umd.js:10011)
    at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent0.detectChangesInternal (AppComponent.template.js:121)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:9996)
```

I have no idea where this error comes from. Here is my code:

model.service.ts

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

import { Model } from '../../class/model/model';


@Injectable()
export class ModelService
{
    constructor(private http: Http){}
    private modelUrl = '../../server/clientFunc/getModel.php';

    getModel (): Promise<Model> {
        return this.http.get(this.modelUrl).toPromise().then(response => response.json()).catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

catch-data.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }            from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import {Model} from '../../class/model/model';
import {ModelService} from '../../services/model/model.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'catch-data',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/catch-data/catch-data.component.html',
    providers: [ModelService]
})

export class CatchDataComponent implements OnInit
{
    constructor(private modelService:ModelService) {
    }
    model:Model;
    errorMessage:string;
    testItem = "Test-Item";

    ngOnInit():any {
       this.getModel();
    }

    getModel() {
        this.modelService.getModel()
            .then(response => {
                this.model = new Model();
                this.model.deserialize(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.errorMessage = error;
                console.log(error);
            }); // TODO: Display
    }
}
```

and the model.ts

```
export class Model
{
    id:number;
    name:string;

    constructor(){
    }

    deserialize(object){
        this.name = object.name;
        this.id = object.id;
    }

}
```

The template looks like:

```
<h1>Search and catch data</h1>
<h3>Model: {{testItem}}</h3>
<div>Name: {{model.name}}</div>
```

So as I could detect the `CatchDataComponent` gets null as I call `getModel()`.

So in `ngOnInit` this is not null but a call later in `getModel()` `this` is `null`.

I have no Idea why this happens.
I hope you have an idea or any suggestions.

Comment: The exception happens with the code exactly as above? Usually this is when you pass a function like `doSomethingWithCallback(this.someFunc)` (like you do in `catch(this.handleError)` or if you use `function()` instead of `() =>`. In `catch(this.handleError)` this should not matter because `handleError()` doesn't refer to `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could use the Elvis operator:

```
<div>Name: {{model?.name}}</div>
```

because the `model` property is loaded asynchronously and not available when the `model.name` is evaluated at first...

Comment: so I have to use this operator each time I use some properties which are async loaded? Is there a better way to handle this ?